# How can I convert a string that has a lot of white space and contains what would be duplicate keys into a dictionary using Python?

Tags: string, dictionary

I have a list of strings that I need to convert into a dictionary. The strings within the list contain a lot of whitespace and '\n'. It looks something like:

```
    my_list = ['Jim:     5\n', 'Sue     : 182\n', 'Jim: 112.2\n', 'Ron: abx']
```

I need to convert this to a dictionary with the names as keys, and, if it's a duplicate key, adding the value to the already added key:value pair. And I need to be able to ignore the values that aren't floats/integers. So, I want to come up with something like this:

```
    my_dict = {'Jim': 117.2, 'Sue': 182, 'Ron': 0}
```

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
The answer below was really helpful. Thanks! I changed the suggested code to this because i need the values to be floats:

```
    my_list = ['Jim:     5\n', 'Sue     : 182\n', 'Jim: 112.2\n', 'Ron: abx']
    result = {}
    for ele in my_list:
        (key, val) = ele.split(':')
        if key not in result:
            key = ''.join(e for e in key if e.isalnum())
            val = ''.join(e for e in val if e.isalnum())
            try:
                float(val)
                result[key] = float(val)
            except:
                result[key] = 0


    print(result)
```

This was the output:

```
    {'Jim': 5.0, 'Sue': 182.0, 'Ron': 0}
```

However, I don't know how to get the value for the second Jim ('Jim: 112.2\n') to get added to the first Jim key:value pair instead of just being ignored. Any tips?

I need it to return this:

```
    {'Jim': 117.2, 'Sue': 182.0, 'Ron': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['Jim:     5\n', 'Sue     : 182\n', 'Jim: 112.2\n', 'Ron: abx']
result = {}
for ele in my_list:
    (key, val) = ele.split(':')
    key = ''.join(e for e in key if e.isalnum())
    val = ''.join(e for e in val if e.isalnum())
    result[key] = val
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the `join` but directly utilizing the output from `split` using indexes

```
my_list = ['Jim:     5\n', 'Sue     : 182\n', 'Jim: 112.2\n', 'Ron: abx']

result = {}

for ele in my_list:
    temp = ele.split(':')
    #### Extracting the key using index - 0 and striping and whitespaces
    key = temp[0].strip()
    #### Extracting the value using index - 1 and striping and whitespaces
    val = float(temp[1].strip())
    
    #### Key existence , if the key exists , add the existing value to the current value
    if key in result:
       result[key] += val
    else:
       result[key] = val

>>> print(result)
{'Jim': 117.2, 'Sue': 182.0}
```